# Why some material is waterproof while breathable?

Tags: everyday-life

I am an outdoor lover. Sometimes I am addicted to the jackets made of high-tech materials. There are some materials waterproof while breathable, I wonder how this is possible.

They(Liquid water and gas water) are water molecures anyway. Is it possible mainly because for liquid water we must consider the surface tension? Are there any rather deep physical reasons? You can search material gore-tex for a reference.

Comment: See PTFE the material is like a semi permeable membrane imagine small pores that blocks water droplets but big enough to allow water vapor to escape.

Comment: You are right to say that since water molecules tend to stick together due to surface tension, deep physical reasons? Perhaps you are thinking since water is dielectric so... relax cheer the effects will be negligible enough to completely ignore. Anyway drinks on me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Gore-tex is very porous. This lets water vapor (and air) out, but the pores are not large enough to let liquid water in. The reason water cannot go through the pores is because they are only 1 micrometer larges. So, water vapor can diffuse through but water in liquid form cannot pass through. [source 1](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/goretex.html) and [source 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gore-Tex).

Comment: Goretex also doesn't let liquid water out. So once your sweat condenses, you can stew in it. My worst ever purchase - Goretex lined boots.

Comment: @RobJeffries  Sounds pretty bad. Yep, the pores won't let liquid water in (or out).